# Need uniq output for df -h and remove duliplicate values

Tags: shell, awk, ssh, grep, disk

I have created below shell script with for Jason output. I am getting the correct results ouput but few deplicte mount points are also showing up. I would like to get the uniq output by removing the duplicate

```sh
disks=$(ssh username@${server} df -h |\
egrep "/ABC" | \
awk '{print "{" "\"total\":" "\"" $3 "\"" ", \"used\":" "\"" $4"\"" ", \"mountPoint\":" "\""$5"\"" "},"}' && \
ssh username@${server} df -h |\
egrep "/XYZ" | \
awk '{print "{" "\"total\":" "\"" $3 "\"" ", \"used\":" "\"" $4"\"" ", \"mountPoint\":" "\""$5"\"" "},"}'
 && \
ssh username@${server} df -h |\
egrep "/RRR" |\
awk '{print "{" "\"total\":" "\"" $3 "\"" ", \"used\":" "\"" $4"\"" ", \"mountPoint\":" "\""$5"\"" "},"}' && ssh username@${server} df -h |egrep "/CCC" | awk '{print "{" "\"total\":" "\"" $3 "\"" ", \"used\":" "\"" $4"\"" ", \"mountPoint\":" "\""$5"\"" "}"}')
```

Output I am getting now is:

```
976M   92M  834M  10% /ABC
2.0G  3.5M  1.9G   1% /ABC---- duplicate mount points (need to remove one entry. i.e. /AAA)
99G   23G   71G  25% /XYZ
500G   53G  448G  11% /RRR
```

Comment: Output I am getting now is: 976M 92M 834M 10% /ABC 2.0G 3.5M 1.9G 1% /ABC---- duplicate mount points (need to remove one entry. i.e. /AAA) 99G 23G 71G 25% /XYZ 500G 53G 448G 11% /RRR

Comment: Output I am getting now is: 
976M 92M 834M 10% /ABC 
2.0G 3.5M 1.9G 1% /ABC---- duplicate mount points (need to remove one entry. i.e. /AAA) 
99G 23G 71G 25% /XYZ 
500G 53G 448G 11% /RRR

Comment: you don't need to run `df -h` 4 X. Run it once and have your awk script use a pattern match like `/\/RRR/{do stuff for RRR recs}; /\/CCC/{ do stuff for CCC recs}... etc`. As written now, your Q is too hard to read AND you complicating it with the `disks=$(...)`. Stuff, Just get the `awk` filter to work and then you can add `disks=$(..)` at the end. Either update your Q with info supplied in comments, or delete them as they look like duplciate info. Use the `{}` tool from the edit menu on mouse-seleted text to get proper text/data/errMsgs formatting. Good luck.

Comment: `awk` is the wrong tool for this job. Use a tool like `jq` that natively understands how to generate valid, correctly-quoted JSON.

Comment: Why would you write this code at all? Why run `df` three different times? Why not run `awk` *once*, filtering for the three mount points you care about from the output of a single `df` call?

Answer (score 3):

A much more appropriate tool for this job is `jq`. Consider (note for folks testing this that the `ABC|XYZ|RR` regex should be changed to match at least one local mount point):

```
df -h | jq -R '
  select(test("/(ABC|XYZ|RR)/"; "")) |
  split("[[:space:]]+"; "") as $line |
  { "total": $line[3], "used": $line[4], "mountPoint": $line[5] } 
'
```

`awk` doesn't understand JSON syntax, so if your mount point names contain characters that need to be escaped for the output document to be valid, `awk` doesn't know to do so. `jq`, by contrast, automatically does all quoting and escaping needed for output to be valid JSON, no matter what your input is.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. You can omit egrep

Since you are using `awk`, you can completely omit `egrep` and shorten your code.

Instead of

```sh
ssh <> | egrep <pattern> | awk '{<commands>}'
```

you can use

```sh
ssh <> | awk '<pattern> {<commands>}'
```

I.e.:

```sh
disks=$(ssh username@${server} df -h |\
awk '/\/ABC/ {print "{" "\"total\":" "\"" $3 "\"" ", \"used\":" "\"" $4"\"" ", \"mountPoint\":" "\""$5"\"" "},"}' &&\
ssh username@${server} df -h  | \
awk '/\/XYZ/ {print "{" "\"total\":" "\"" $3 "\"" ", \"used\":" "\"" $4"\"" ", \"mountPoint\":" "\""$5"\"" "},"}' && \
ssh username@${server} df -h  | \
awk '/\/RRR/ {print "{" "\"total\":" "\"" $3 "\"" ", \"used\":" "\"" $4"\"" ", \"mountPoint\":" "\""$5"\"" "},"}' && \
ssh username@${server} df -h  | \
awk '/\/CCC/{print "{" "\"total\":" "\"" $3 "\"" ", \"used\":" "\"" $4"\"" ", \"mountPoint\":" "\""$5"\"" "}"}')
```

## 2. `awk`: how-to print only 1st occurrence of pattern

You can try this:

```sh
awk '/regex/ {print $1; exit}'
```

I.e.

```sh
disks=$(ssh username@${server} df -h | \
awk '/\/ABC/ {print "{" "\"total\":" "\"" $3 "\"" ", \"used\":" "\"" $4"\"" ", \"mountPoint\":" "\""$5"\"" "},"; exit}' && \
ssh username@${server} df -h  | \
awk '/\/XYZ/ {print "{" "\"total\":" "\"" $3 "\"" ", \"used\":" "\"" $4"\"" ", \"mountPoint\":" "\""$5"\"" "},"; exit}' && \
ssh username@${server} df -h  | \
awk '/\/RRR/ {print "{" "\"total\":" "\"" $3 "\"" ", \"used\":" "\"" $4"\"" ", \"mountPoint\":" "\""$5"\"" "},"; exit}' && \
ssh username@${server} df -h  | \
awk '/\/CCC/{print "{" "\"total\":" "\"" $3 "\"" ", \"used\":" "\"" $4"\"" ", \"mountPoint\":" "\""$5"\"" "}"; exit}')
```

**P.S.**
There is a great collection of `awk` samples: [Useful One-Line Scripts for awk command.](https://gist.github.com/himalay/9352929)